# Cannot subscript a value of type '[UIImage]' with an index of type 'CGFloat'

Tags: swift, xcode

I have this error.

**Cannot subscript a value of type '[UIImage]' with an index of type 'CGFloat'**

Why it is happen?

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y > self.view.frame.height) {
        //(1/10) because we are changing the scrollView every 1/10 of the screen
        let pictureCount = scrollView.contentOffset.y/scrollView.frame.height*(1/10)
        imageView.image = images[pictureCount]
    }

}
```

Comment: `imageView.image = images[Int(pictureCount)]` Convert CGFloat to Int for  accessing arrays with index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** use `CGFloat` to index arrays in Swift, you can fix it with a simple cast to `Int`.

```swift
let priceCount : CGFloat = 3 /* just for testing purposes */
let images = [UIImage]()
let imageView = UIImageView()

imageView.image = images[Int(priceCount)]
```

This cast was pointed out by @prekshya basnet in the comments.

---

Arrays only have `Int` positions, such as:

`array[0]`, `array[1]`, `array[2]`

If `CGFloats` could index arrays, that would create ambiguity, since something like `array[0.5]` could be an accessing option

**Note:** The cast from `CGFloat` to `Int`, will simply remove decimal values without rounding it, which means that it doesn't matter if you have `Int(CGFloat(0.1))` or `Int(CGFloat(0.9))`, this will always result `0`.